# Insert data to a pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have 3 tables: `posts`, `tags`, `post_tag`.

Each `Post` has many tags so I use `hasMany` method for them. But when I choose for example 3 tags in my dropdown list, I can't add them to `post_tag` and as the result I can't select and show each post's tags.

My `Post` model:

```
 class Post extends Eloquent{
 public function tag()
         {
           return  $this->hasMany('Tag');
         }
    }
```

My `Tag` model:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent{
 public function post()
         {
           return  $this->belongsToMany('Post');
         }
```

}

And my `postController`:

```
class postController extends BaseController{

public function addPost(){

    $post=new Post;

    $post_title=Input::get('post_title');
    $post_content=Input::get('post_content');
    $tag_id=Input::get('tag');

    $post->tag()->sync($tag_id);
    $post->save();
```

I expect to save this `post_id` save to `post_tag` table with its tag ids,
but it doesn't work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If a relation has a pivot table then both sides of it should be `belongsToMany`. Also you should really name the method `tags` not `tag` as it's a *Many relationship.

Comment: @alexrussell yes you're right :). and other problem was `$post->tag()->sync($tag_id);
    $post->save();`  these senteces place should be replace. thanks

Comment: I've added an answer that explains my comment a little more and includes your own correction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a basic idea right, but there are a few issues with your code. Some are stopping it from working and some are just conventional issues.

First off, this is a `belongsTomany` relationship (you have a pivot table) so you must define both sides of the relationship as `belongsToMany` (even if `hasMany` is the way you think about one or both of the side of it). This is because Laravel expects a certain database structure with the two different relationship types.

Another issue (that you found yourself) is that you are adding the tags to the relation (via `->tag()->sync()` before you've actually saved the post. You must first save the post (so that laravel knows what ID to add to the pivot table for `post_id`) and then add the relations. If you are worried about the tags part failing and then having an inconsistent database you should use transactions.

Finally, the 'convention' errors you have is that a belongs-to-many relationship, by definition, involves collections of results. As such, `tag` and `post` shoudl be `tags` and `posts` respectively.

So here's my rewritten version of your code:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}

class Tag extends Eloquent
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}

class PostController extends BaseController
{
    public function addPost()
    {
        // assume it won't work
        $success = false;

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            $post = new Post;

            // maybe some validation here...

            $post->title = Input::get('post_title');
            $post->content = Input::get('post_content');

            if ($post->save()) {
                $tag_ids = Input::get('tags');
                $post->tags()->sync($tag_ids);
                $success = true;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // maybe log this exception, but basically it's just here so we can rollback if we get a surprise
        }

        if ($success) {
            DB::commit();
            return Redirect::back()->withSuccessMessage('Post saved');
        } else {
            DB::rollback();
            return Redirect::back()->withErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

Now a lot of that controller code centres around the transaction stuff - if you don't care too much about that then you're all good to remove it. Also there are several ways to do that transaction stuff - I've gone with one that's not ideal but gets the point across in a minimal amount of code.

Answer (score 9):

To insert you data into pivot table name **diplome_user**, just follow my example: my pivot table looking like:

[image]

```
//this is Diplome Model

    class Diplome extends Model
    {
    public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','diplome_user')->withPivot('etablissement', 'annee', 'mention');;
        }
    }
```

now inside you my DiplomeController, I'm able to make this query:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

because I need a user, I just take the connected one, after it, I create one instance of Diplome like:

```
$diplome = new Diplome();
$diplome->libelle = "the name";
$diplome->decription= "description of the ...";
$diplome->save();
```

now the most important step is:

```
   $diplome->users()->attach($user, ['etablissement'=> 'bib',
                                            'annee'=>'2015',
                                            'mention'=>'AB',
                                            ]);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: The class  naming is so wrong..."A diplome belongsToMany users is wrong on many ways"... 
Normally a user HasMany Diplomes and Diplomes belongto a one User

Answer (score 4):

The `sync()` method wants an array. It should work if you just put the tag id within one, like so:

```
$post->tag()->sync([$tag_id]);
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()` . it appears always :(

Comment: @joelhinz as far as I can discern the code above would indeed be sending an array - `$tag_id` comes form `Input::get('tag')` which, in the intro, OP says "when I choose for example 3 tags in my dropdown list" which suggests it's an array-like input. That said, I guess we shouldn't assume.