# How to save checkbox data to pivot in RegisterController

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I need to save data from register.blade.php to the RegisterController in Laravel since I added a new line in the default registration page with different checkboxes where you can choose a type of restaurant(italian, spanish etc).
So a users upon registrating can choose email, name etc and the type of restaurant they want to register in the platform.

I don't know how to save that data(types) to my pivot named type_user.

This is inside RegisterController

```
  protected function create(array $data)
  {
      dump($data);
      return User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
          'slug' => $this->createSlug($data['name']),
          'address' => $data['address'],
          'vat_number' => $data['vat_number'],
          'types' => $data['types'],
      ]);

  }
```

This is my code in register.blade

```
<section>
  @foreach($types as $type)
  <div class="d-inline-block">
                                        
  <input type="checkbox" name="types[]" id="type{{$loop->iteration}}" value="{{$type->id}}"
              required>

  <label class= "col-form-label" for="type{{$loop->iteration}}">
                {{$type->name}}
   </label>
   </div>

   @endforeach

         @error('types')
           <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
           <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
         @enderror

      </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please make your research before asking question also for Laravel the documentation is quite clear, you should read it. However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547376/insert-data-to-a-pivot-table-in-laravel here is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'slug' => $this->createSlug($data['name']),
    'address' => $data['address'],
    'vat_number' => $data['vat_number']
]);

$user->types()->sync($data['types']);

return $user;
```

Make sure you have defined `types` as a relationship in user model.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you vote for the answer and mark it as working?